# Parametric generation of a plane

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to parametrically generate a plane with a given `width` and `height`. This should be intensely simple, but has been intensely frustrating instead: my code works for all square sizes at or under 16x16, and then it starts messing up.

[image: Wireframe Map]

**Generating vertices**

Nothing special here, just laying out verts by rows and columns.

```
Float3* vertices = new Float3[width * height];
int i = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
        i = (r * width) + c;
        vertices[i] = Float3(c, 0, r);
    }
}
```

**Generating indices**

[image: Generation Order]

Black number = Vertex index, Red number = Order

Each vertex needs 6 slots to place their indices in, aside from the edges.

```
numIndices = ((width - 1) * (height - 1)) * 6;
GLubyte* indices = new GLubyte[numIndices];
i = 0; // Index of current working vertex on the map
int j = -1; // Index on indices array
for (int r = 0; r < height - 1; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < width - 1; c++) {
        i = (r * width) + c;
        indices[++j] = i;
        indices[++j] = i + height + 1;
        indices[++j] = i + height;
        indices[++j] = i;
        indices[++j] = i + 1;
        indices[++j] = i + 1 + height;
    }
}
```

Where is the logic going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overflowing the limit of GLubyte, which can hold a maximum value of 255. Try using GLushort instead.

Comment: I feel ridiculous but that was exactly the problem. Thank you so much.